# ln -sf no longer works

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a folder with the following contents. I am wanting to change the symbolic link in a single atomic transaction without deleting it.

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Apr 10 13:47 2012-03-19
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Apr 10 13:44 2012-04-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Mar 19 15:28 current -> 2012-03-19
```

I figured out at one time that the following would do it:

```
# ln -sf 2012-04-10 current
```

However, it doesn't take. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: atomic transaction on a file system?!

Comment: do an ls of current, I bet you will find your symbolic link there.

Comment: pfo: Sorry for using the wrong terminology. I've got a stronger database background and that was the best way I could think of to communicate my point quickly. I figured you would understand what I meant even if the terminology wasn't correct. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the following

```
ln -sfn 2012-04-10 current
```

The reason

```
   -n, --no-dereference
          treat destination that is a symlink to a directory as if it were a normal file
```